# Are there any customizable vulnerability notification services?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

Are there any services (free or otherwise) that provide information on new vulnerabilities for a given piece of technology?

For example, say I want to be updated of all new Wordpress vulnerabilities via RSS or email? What would be my best option?

Comment: There is no best option. [National vulnerability database](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search) offers CVE feeds which can be filtered by [IfThisThenThat](http://ifttt.com) or [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com). There are also mailing lists for most popular pieces of software.

Comment: I use the National vulnerability database as a basis for [SecureIT](https://secureit.io) that shows you new vulnerabilities that your server/container/webapp might have.

Comment: Vulmon Alerts (https://alerts.vulmon.com) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: https://secalerts.co is also a free service that's been running for nearly 3 years now that does exactly this. Disclaimer: I run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Exploit Database](http://www.exploit-db.com/) have a [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/exploitdb) that updates regularly.

You could use [tweetalarm](http://www.tweetalarm.com/) with the keyword `[webapps] - Wordpress`, and set it to email you whenever a tweet containing that keyword is used.  Then you would know about verified exploits for WordPress as soon as they are added to the database.

Comment: Tweetalarm now seems to be a dead link.

Answer (score 7):

2020 update: CVE Details has *[silently stopped being updated](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/year-2020/vulnerabilities.html)*.

---

[**CVE Details**](http://cvedetails.com/) allows you to "generate a custom RSS feed or an embedable vulnerability list widget or a json API call url", filterable on a large range of fields including [product](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/Wordpress-Wordpress.html).

Comment: Looks like you only filter the feed by 1 product at a time, is that right? Would be great to have a collated feed based on multiple products you were interested in.

Comment: Yes, I'm not aware of that capability if it has it.

Comment: Seems up-to-date as of 2023-03-21

Answer (score 2):

[**US-CERT**](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/) provides a free alerting service. They also have feeds from NCAS, which you can sign up for here:  https://www.us-cert.gov/mailing-lists-and-feeds

While they don't offer a specific technology or product feed, you could filter them out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[**Secunia**](http://secunia.com/community/advisories/) has a nice feed and allows one to sort by vendor as well as product. Long ago one could sign up for email alerts for free, but I don't think that is the case anymore.